Successive divisions in a list
Suppose I have a list:
list = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l}

How can I make a new list which contains successive divisions of old lists like {a/b, b/c...} etc?
I tried this code(a bit long, in my opinion):
newlist = #[[1]]/#[[2]] & /@ Partition[list, 2, 1]

Can there be other efficient alternatives as well?
Edit
This question is different from Determining moving ratios over a list because there the objective was to know how fast values in a list approach unity, but here, I just wished to find the successive divisions. Also, this question has led to many more answers than that. Even then, I have no issues if moderators wish to close it.

"there the objective was to know how fast values in a list approach unity" But by reading the title and the code sample in the question, it's clear the goal of the question is to know how fast values in a list approach unity by determining moving ratios over a list, so I don't think your question is different.

Fine, I have no issues if it's closed.

1/Ratios[list]


I learned the existence of Ratios[] from @cvgmt's answer.

very nice answer +1:)

The above answers are nice and use advanced builtin commands.
But a simple one Table command will do as well (and much easier to understand by any one, even those who do not know Mathematica :)
Table[ lis[[n]]/lis[[n+1]] ,{n,1,Length[lis]-1}]


As for efficiency, which is your main question, I do not know now.
May be someone could do some timing on a very large list and compare with the other answers.
My understanding is that the Table command is an optimized command in Mathematica.
Update
Here is timing on 10 million long list of numbers.
f1[lis_List] := #[[1]]/#[[2]] & /@ Partition[lis, 2, 1]
f2[lis_List] := 1/Ratios[lis]
f3[lis_List] := Reverse@Ratios@Reverse@lis 
f4[lis_List] := FoldPairList[{Divide[##], #2} &, lis[[1]], Rest@lis, Identity][[All,1]]
f5[lis_List] := Most@lis/Rest@lis 
f6[lis_List] := MapApply[Divide]@Partition[lis, 2, 1]
f7[lis_List] := MovingMap[Apply[Divide], lis, 1]
f8[lis_List] := Table[lis[[n]]/lis[[n + 1]], {n, 1, Length[lis] - 1}]
f9[lis_List] := SequenceCases[lis, {a_, b_} :> a/b, Overlaps -> True]

lis = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, 10^7];
data = Table[{fun, RepeatedTiming[fun[lis]][[1]]}, 
    {fun, {f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9}}];
Grid[SortBy[data, Last], Frame -> All]


So the fastest is
  Reverse@Ratios@Reverse@lis 

The commands MapApply[Divide]@Partition[lis, 2, 1] and 1/Ratios[lis] were equally fast.
The table command got 4th place out of 9. Not bad for simple command. But it looks like someone here does not like Table command as this answer was downvoted :)
Update 2
fyi, Moved the performance result code to its own community wiki below.

@user1066 the analysis part is now a wiki (below). Wiki means any one can edit and add their answer there and re-run it. So feel free to do that if you wish.

list = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l};
Reverse@Ratios@Reverse@list


{a/b, b/c, c/d, d/e, e/f, f/g, g/h, h/i, i/j, j/k, k/l}


Divide[Most[lis], Rest[lis]]

  (* {a/b, b/c, c/d, d/e, e/f, f/g, g/h, h/i, i/j, j/k, k/l} *)

Or
MapApply[Divide]@Partition[list, 2, 1]

(* {a/b, b/c, c/d, d/e, e/f, f/g, g/h, h/i, i/j, j/k, k/l} *)

Or
BlockMap[Apply[Divide], list, 2, 1]

(* {a/b, b/c, c/d, d/e, e/f, f/g, g/h, h/i, i/j, j/k, k/l} *)

Or
MovingMap[Apply[Divide], list, 1]

(* {a/b, b/c, c/d, d/e, e/f, f/g, g/h, h/i, i/j, j/k, k/l} *)

A Note on a (Surprising) Timing

On my machine
Divide[Most[list], Rest[list]]    (1)

is significantly faster than the following, at least for integers
Most[list]/Rest[list]             (2) 

Writing f5mod[lis_List] := Divide[Most@lis, Rest@lis] and then running the code given by @Nasser below produces the following timings:


function (1) is about 18-fold faster than function (2)
function (1) is about 3-fold slower than Reverse@Ratios@Reverse@lis


For something different:
list = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l};
FoldPairList[{Divide[##], #2} &, a, Rest@list, Identity][[All, 1]]

->
{a/b, b/c, c/d, d/e, e/f, f/g, g/h, h/i, i/j, j/k, k/l}


I am moving the timing part of my answer here, to a community wiki, so any one can update it if new answers are given, so I do not have to keep track myself.
Feel free to edit and add your answer and re-run this if you want. This is the current list of answers of now.  I had to reduce the length of the list to only one 100,000 from before, which was 10 million, as I was getting

General::nomem: The current computation was aborted because there was
insufficient memory available to complete the computation.

When I just added some new answers. Not sure which one of the new answers added caused this extra memory need. It one of the ones after f9 which needed much RAM now. I have 128 GB RAM on my PC.
Add your code to the end of this:
f1[lis_List] := #[[1]]/#[[2]] & /@ Partition[lis, 2, 1]
f2[lis_List] := 1/Ratios[lis]
f3[lis_List] := Reverse@Ratios@Reverse@lis
f4[lis_List] := FoldPairList[{Divide[##], #2} &, lis[[1]], Rest@lis, Identity][[All, 1]]
f5[lis_List] := Most@lis/Rest@lis
f6[lis_List] := MapApply[Divide]@Partition[lis, 2, 1]
f7[lis_List] := MovingMap[Apply[Divide], lis, 1]
f8[lis_List] := Table[lis[[n]]/lis[[n + 1]], {n, 1, Length[lis] - 1}]
f9[lis_List] := Module[{a, b}, SequenceCases[lis, {a_, b_} :> a/b, Overlaps -> True]]
f10[lis_List] := Most[lis/RotateLeft[lis]]
f11[lis_List] := Module[{n = Length[lis]}, lis[[1 ;; n - 1]]/lis[[2 ;; n]]]
f12[lis_List] := Module[{fun}, 
  fun = Map[Divide @@ #[[-2 ;;]] &@*List @@ # &]@Rest@Accumulate@# &; 
  fun@lis]
f13[lis_List] := Map[Divide @@ #[[-2 ;;]] &]@FoldList[Append, {}, lis][[3 ;;]]
f14[lis_List] := Map[Divide @@ #[[-2 ;;]] &@Take[lis, #] &]@Range[2, Length@lis]

And now do the test
lis = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, 10^5];

(*update this table command if you add more f_n *)

data = Table[{fun, RepeatedTiming[fun[lis]][[1]]}, 
   {fun, {f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10, f11, f12, f13, f14}}];

Grid[SortBy[data, Last], Frame -> All]


As of now, the fastest is Reverse@Ratios@Reverse@lis as seen by the above result.

Interesting! If we seek for execution speed, it seems "pipeline of unary operators" is the first choice.

list = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l}
SequenceCases[list, {a_, b_} :> a/b, Overlaps -> True]


{a/b, b/c, c/d, d/e, e/f, f/g, g/h, h/i, i/j, j/k, k/l}


EDIT
Drawing inspiration from this and using the 6th undocumented argument of Partition as suggested by @kglr :
Partition[list, 2, 1, {1, -1}, {}, Divide]

delivers the same result as above.

There are an amazing number of ways to accomplish any task... here's one using Part:
list = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l};
n = Length[list];
list[[1 ;; n - 1]]/list[[2 ;; n]]

{a/b, b/c, c/d, d/e, e/f, f/g, g/h, h/i, i/j, j/k, k/l}


list = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l};


Using Accumulate:
fun = Map[Divide @@ #[[-2 ;;]] &@*List @@ # &]@Rest@Accumulate@# &;

fun@list


{a/b, b/c, c/d, d/e, e/f, f/g, g/h, h/i, i/j, j/k, k/l}

Or using FoldList:
Map[Divide @@ #[[-2 ;;]] &]@FoldList[Append, {}, list][[3 ;;]]


{a/b, b/c, c/d, d/e, e/f, f/g, g/h, h/i, i/j, j/k, k/l}

Or using Take:
Map[Divide @@ #[[-2 ;;]] &@Take[list, #] &]@Range[2, Length@list]


{a/b, b/c, c/d, d/e, e/f, f/g, g/h, h/i, i/j, j/k, k/l}


Most[list/RotateLeft[list]]


{a/b, b/c, c/d, d/e, e/f, f/g, g/h, h/i, i/j, j/k, k/l}

